# Unable to drive 7 segment 6 digits multiplexed display using 74HC595 and arduino

Tags: arduino, display, shift-register, 7segmentdisplay, 74hc595

I have reverse engineered some existing circuit that was given to me which consists of a multiplexed 6 digits 7 segments displays driven by 2 darligton arrays and BD227 transistors.

The original circuit had an AT89 driving all the segments and digits on individual pins and used to receive data from a MAX232, I wanted to connect the displays to an Arduino so to be able to drive the digits myself.

This is the circuit:

[image]

I have by manged to drive all the digits and DP connecting each segment pin and each digit directly to the Arduino pins utilising the SevSeg library. The code works very well, with no flickering, high brightness and no ghosting.

Hardware config set to `N_TRANSISTORS`.

The code I have used is as follows:

```
#include "SevSeg.h"
SevSeg sevseg; //Instantiate a seven segment controller object

void setup() {
  byte numDigits = 5;
  byte digitPins[] = {10,11,12,13,A0};
  byte segmentPins[] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2};
  bool resistorsOnSegments = true; // 'false' means resistors are on digit pins
  byte hardwareConfig = N_TRANSISTORS; // See README.md for options
  bool updateWithDelays = false; // Default 'false' is Recommended
  bool leadingZeros = false; // Use 'true' if you'd like to keep the leading zeros
  bool disableDecPoint = false; // Use 'true' if your decimal point doesn't exist or isn't connected
  
  sevseg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments,
  updateWithDelays, leadingZeros
  , disableDecPoint);
  sevseg.setBrightness(0);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  sevseg.setChars("Hello");
  sevseg.refreshDisplay();
}
```

I am now trying to attempt to drive the display using two 74HC595 and the SevSegShift library, a fork of SevSeg that adds support for shift registers, although I did not have great luck so far.

I have also tried the hybrid configuration (digits connected directly to Arduino and segments driven by the shift register) as listed on library's git but with the same results.

I am able to light up each digit although I am not able to control each individual segment, all I am getting are the 8 segments always light up, I have tried to add a delay in the loop to see if there was some segments sequence but all I'm getting is all the segments on or off altogether.

I have tried all the HardwareConfig settings:

`COMMON_CATHODE`
`COMMON_ANODE`
`N_TRANSISTORS`
`P_TRANSISTORS`
`NP_COMMMON_CATHODE`
`NP_COMMMON_ANODE`

Although I do not see any difference beside all the segments being full brightness or slightly dimmed.

My question is could it be something to do with the darlington arrays interfering with the logic?

This is the code I have at the moment (I am using the hybrid configuration):

```
#include "SevSegShift.h"

#define SHIFT_PIN_DS   13 /* Data input PIN */
#define SHIFT_PIN_STCP 12 /* Shift Register Storage PIN */
#define SHIFT_PIN_SHCP 11 /* Shift Register Shift PIN */

//Instantiate a seven segment controller object (with Shift Register functionality)
SevSegShift sevsegshift(
                  SHIFT_PIN_DS, 
                  SHIFT_PIN_SHCP, 
                  SHIFT_PIN_STCP, 
                  1, /* number of shift registers there is only 1 Shiftregister 
                        used for all Segments (digits are on Controller)
                        default value = 2 (see SevSegShift example)
                        */
                  true /* Digits are connected to Arduino directly 
                          default value = false (see SevSegShift example)
                        */
                );

void setup() {
  byte numDigits = 5;
  byte digitPins[] = {2,3,4,5,6}; // Arduino pins
  byte segmentPins[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}; // 74HC595 pins
  bool resistorsOnSegments = true; // 'false' means resistors are on digit pins
  byte hardwareConfig = N_TRANSISTORS; // See README.md for options
  bool updateWithDelays = false; // Default 'false' is Recommended
  bool leadingZeros = false; // Use 'true' if you'd like to keep the leading zeros
  bool disableDecPoint = false; // Use 'true' if your decimal point doesn't exist or isn't connected

  sevsegshift.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments,
  updateWithDelays, leadingZeros, disableDecPoint);
  sevsegshift.setBrightness(0);
}

void loop() {
  sevsegshift.setChars("Hello");
  sevsegshift.refreshDisplay();
}
```

The 74HC595 connections are not show in the schematic although I have used a configuration simila

Here the schematic of my shift registers:

[image]